# Referencing a query in a different event in the database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Have the following code for a crosstab query that exports to Excel. At the beginning of the code, I reference a query that I created in the QBE grid called *1ACTMasterQuery* and everything works.

But, I have copied that SQL into VBA in a string called *MasterPivot*, and it executes just fine. But I want the following to use *PivotMaster* rather than *1ACTMasterQuery*.

How do I change the code so that uses the data from *PivotMaster*?

The error says that it can't find *PivotMaster*. I know that it is a select query and need to fake out the system so that it thinks its a table as in:

```vb
     CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "SKbyYrByMo", SKbyYrByMo
```

Tried several guesses but none of them work.

```vb
 SKbyYrByMo = "TRANSFORM Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS SumOfExtension" 
 & _
 " SELECT [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku, 
 Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS [Total Of Extension]" & _
 " FROM 1ACTMasterQuery" & _
 " GROUP BY [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku" & _
 " PIVOT [1ACTMasterQuery].MonthNo"

 'Create the view/query to like a table object
 CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "SKbyYrByMo", SKbyYrByMo

 '-----Set Query Running Status--------------------------------------------- 
 -
 Me.QueryStatus.Visible = True
 Me.QueryStatus.SetFocus
 Me.QueryStatus.BackColor = vbGreen
 Me.QueryStatus.Text = "     Processing"
```

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"SKbyYrByMo", _
"C:\Users\John\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", _
True

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "SKbyYrByMo"

'-----End query Staus-------------------------------------------------------
Me.QueryStatus.Text = " "
Me.SKbYbM.SetFocus
Me.QueryStatus.Visible = False
MsgBox "Complete"
```

Thanks

Comment: I am confused at what your problem is, possibly because of name conflict. How does *SKbyYrByMo* and *PivotMaster* relate? And you mention the *error says that it can't find PivotMaster*...what line causes that error?

Comment: 1ACTMasterQuery, a select query, was created in the QBE grid, and it collects data from a transaction table, creates alias names, and derives columns.  That query is input to SKbyYrByMo, which is a crosstab query the output of which is exported to EXCEL via DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet.  I need to have the PivotMaster query in the form That contains the buttons.  So I copied the SQL and set it up to run in an on click event.  The event runs when referencing the 1ACTMasterQuery which is in the query list in ACCESS. But I want the code to reference the code in VBA, the query called Pivot Master.

Comment: Still confused. There is no *PivotMaster* in posted code. Please edit. Queries are objects in the database. VBA string variables (whatever you name it or whatever it is assigned -SQL code or other) are not queries. It sounds like you want to replace *1ACTMasterQuery* in crosstab with a saved *PivotMaster* query which is doable.

Comment: I didn't post Pivot query because of it's size.  Your last line is exactly what I want to do, but I need PivotMaster to be in VB as an SQL string.  PivotMaster starts with: Dim PivotMaster As String
            PivotMaster = "SELECT 
            dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number, 
            dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type, 
            dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku," & _ and goes on from there.

Comment: Everything I've created in on one form. It Contains buttons that export various versions of excel reports.  What I've created will end up in a large run time version of ACCESS and I wanted to help that developer so that he could just import the form and have all of the SQL as part of the form, and not have to contend with stuff external to the form.  Hope that makes sense. If it can't be done, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following routine to create and destroy needed queries with [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn123782.aspx). Also, use a table alias in SQL statements to cut down on length as well as easily replace the source table:

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String 

' DELETE QUERIES IF THEY EXIST
For Each qdef in CurrentDb.QueryDefs
   If qdef.Name = "SKbyYrByMo" Or qdef.Name = "PivotMaster" Then
      CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdef.Name
   End If
Next qdef

' CREATE PivotMaster QUERY
strSQL = "SELECT d.Account_Number, d.Transaction_Type, d.Sku, " & _
         "       d.Extension, d.Year, d.MonthNo" & _
         " FROM dbo_Transaction_Table d"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("PivotMaster", strSQL)
Set qdef = Nothing     ' SAVE NEW QUERY

' CREATE SKbyYrByMo QUERY
strSQL = "TRANSFORM Sum(t.Extension) AS SumOfExtension" & _
         " SELECT t.Year, t.Sku, Sum(t.Extension) AS [Total Of Extension]" & _
         " FROM 1ACTMasterQuery t" & _
         " GROUP BY t.Year, t.Sku" & _
         " PIVOT t.MonthNo"

' REPLACE SOURCE TABLE
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "1ACTMasterQuery", "PivotMaster")

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("SKbyYrByMo", strSQL)
Set qdef = Nothing     ' SAVE NEW QUERY

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "SKbyYrByMo", "C:\Users\John\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", True
```